# wpf: create link on drag and drop to windows explorer

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {      
            TreeViewHitTestInfo tvhti = this.treeView1.HitTest(e.Location);  
             DataObject obj = new DataObject(DataFormat.Filedrop, "C:\\Test.doc"); 
            this.treeView1.DoDragDrop(obj, DragDropEffects.Copy);               
        }
```

I have this piece of code, it works fine. when i drop file on Microsoft Office it open it successfully. But my requirement is if user drop file on desktop or any other location it should create link (*.lnk) to that file, currently it is copying the file.
please guide me if this is achievable or what way should i go forward to get it done?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to drag a piece of text from my application and drop it into notepad, but notepad doesn't support dropping of text into it. I guess it also applies to Windows Explorer. According to me windows explorer doesn't have intelligence to accept a text from an application, recognize it as a file path and create a link. I hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: i think there is no way to find on what target we are dropping file in windows OS :(